# Finding "line of best fit" using linear programming

Tags: algorithm

This is a homework question. I'm asked to find the coefficients of the line of best fit for a given set of n dots(2D). The coefficients are a b c in: ax+by=c.Say there're n dots, use linear programming to find the coefficients that leads to the smallest 'maximum absolute error', defined as: max(|a*xi+b*yi-c|), i ranges from 1-n.

Here's my thought process:

Let M denote the maximum absolute error. The objective of linear programming is to minimize M. Since M is the biggest of all |a*xi+b*yi-c|, it must be bigger than every one of them. So (a*xi+b*yi-c)<= M, and (a*xi+b*yi-c)>= -M, for all i (the second expression is to account for the absolute sign).

I thought this is sufficient to define the problem. When i put the conditions into a solver, it returned a b c all equal to 0, but in reality it shouldn't. I think I'm missing some conditions here. Can someone point it out to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add one extra statement that is: either a or b should not be 0. If both values are 0 you have a valid solution to your system but there is no line with both a and b equal to 0.

EDIT: improving Rerito's suggestion. Any line has either a or b not equal to 0. Alo the lines `(k*a)*x + (k*b)* y + (k*c)` and `(a)*x + (b)* y + (c)` are the same for any non-zero k. So I would say you need to run the solver twice- once when specifying a is 1 and once when specifying b is 1 and after than select the better solution. You have to run the solver twice because it might be the case that the best solution has `a=0` or `b=0`(but not both).

Comment: Interestingly the solver still gives me all 0s as the result. I think adding the condition of either a or b !=0 only forces the solver to get their values infinitely close to 0, which is 0 =\

Comment: @user1926344 Since `p.a.x + p.b.y = p.c` defines the same line as `a.x + b.y = c` (with `p != 0`), specify `a = 1 or b = 1` to your solver :)

Comment: @Rerito you will have to run solver twice to avoid missing the best solution. I have added an edit to my answer. Thanks for this comment.